# nginx reverse proxy setup resulting in strange access-control-allow-origin issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, thin, faye

I have a Rails application setup on Nginx/Passenger on Ubuntu. Recently I added Faye running on Thin which requires adding a reverse proxy server setup in my Nginx config. I managed to get this to work but the setup is very strange: It only works if I access my server from www.mydomain.com and access the reverse proxy using Javascript code at mydomain.com/faye. Although I manage to access the Faye server this way, the Chrome browser console repeatedly flashes Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, so I know this is not a long-term solution. The error makes sense to me but I couldn't fix it after many tries.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load mydomain.com/faye. Origin www.mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The obvious solution would be to access from www.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com/faye, but doing so results in a 502 gateway error. If I strip both www's I also get a 502 error.

I also tried to rewrite www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com in Nginx and access everything from mydomain.com, but it still doesn't work.

Below is my abridged nginx.conf. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
http {
  passenger_root <path_to_passenger_root>
  passenger_ruby <path_to_passenger_ruby>

  <abridged...>

  upstream faye_server {
    server 0.0.0.0:9292;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    root <path_to_root>
    passenger_enabled on;

    <abridged...>

    location /faye {
      proxy_pass http://faye_server;
    }
  }

  <Similar section for listening on port 443>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you know that you can run faye directly on Passenger now? No need to have thin in between.

Check this out: https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#running-the-app-with-passenger

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. Is it possible to have both Faye and Faye-websocket gems working together, since I don't see any Javascript client libraries with Faye-websocket?

Comment: Yes, I think that's how you should do it :)

Comment: Thanks, eventually I got around this issue by adding Varnish in front of Nginx. Now Varnish handles the websocket connections perfectly.